# Initialize class in the same file

Tags: php

This might seem like a stupid question but, is it a good practice to initialize a class or call one of it's functions in the same file? I mean like this:

```
<?php
class MyClass {
    public function __construct($param) {

    }
    public static function MyFunction() {

    }
}

$Obj = new MyClass('hello');
MyClass::MyFunction();
?>
```

This works jut fine, but I'm curios if its a good practice, from a functionality and accessibility point of view.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not good practice. [The PSR](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) even has this codified in their third point:

> Files SHOULD either declare symbols (classes, functions, constants, etc.) or cause side-effects (e.g. generate output, change .ini settings, etc.) but SHOULD NOT do both.

Creating variables, class instances and calling code is a "side effect". This will cause problems if you include the file several times from different places, or simply by implicitly creating a variable in the current scope without any way to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good approach, it's better to define classes in their own files in a proper namespace and better load classes with autoloading. Read about autoloading and composer it's a cleaner way to organize your project.

Answer (score 1):

No. :)

If you are want to use class-based inheritance, you should stick to the coding standard of having separate files just for defining classes. You should have a MyClass.php file declaring just the class and nothing else. Include this file in another php script and instantiate the class there.

However:
The way you write it now is af if you're not interested in the class, but just the one object. Why use class-based inheritance instead of prototypical inheritance. In prototypical inheritance you declare a general object and 'dress it up' with properties and methods:

```
$Obj = (object)[ 'property' => 'value'];
$Obj->method = function() { ... };
```